# installing surround.vim and getting an error message - E149 - no help for surround

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to installing plugins on vim and i managed to install nerdtree and pathogen, now i'm trying to install surround.vim and i'm getting an error message such as E149 no help for surround command. I haven't added anything to the vimrc file but i don't know what i should add to it for this to work can someone please advise on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've installed the Surround plugin in `~/.vim/`, you have to re-generate the help tags database via:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

After that, commands such as `:help surround` should open the corresponding help page.

If you use a plugin manager, you may have to adapt the path. Some managers also can do this update automatically.

Comment: Pathogen has `:Helptags`.

Comment: i couldnt open it as i got a message saying couldnt open for writing when i try to generate the help tags

Comment: should i extract the files to the bundle folder or just follow the orignal folder structure?

Comment: The benefit of bundles is separation; you can easily remove a plugin. But it increases complexity and requires some setup, e.g. Pathogen.